# How do I make an animation run just once in java?

Tags: java, animation

So I am using the framework from a book on how to program games in java and it has an animation class like so:

```
package com.vincent.framework.animation;

import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Animation {

private Frame[] frames;
private double[] frameEndTimes;
private int currentFrameIndex = 0;

private double totalDuration;
private double currentTime;

public Animation(Frame... frames) {
    this.frames = frames;
    frameEndTimes = new double[frames.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < frames.length; i++) {
        Frame f = frames[i];
        totalDuration += f.getDuration();
        frameEndTimes[i] = totalDuration;
    }
}

public synchronized void update(float increment) {
    currentTime += increment;

    if (currentTime > totalDuration) {
        wrapAnimation();
    }

    while (currentTime > frameEndTimes[currentFrameIndex]) {
        currentFrameIndex++;
    }

}

private synchronized void wrapAnimation() {
    currentFrameIndex = 0;
    currentTime %= totalDuration;
}

public synchronized void render(Graphics g, int x, int y) {
    g.drawImage(frames[currentFrameIndex].getImage(), x, y, null);
}

public synchronized void render(Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    g.drawImage(frames[currentFrameIndex].getImage(), x, y, width, height, null);
}

}
```

That is fine if you want the animation to repeat over and over, but how can I make an animation stop when it gets to the last frame? I have tried having an if statement to check if it has reached the last stage, but it would skip frames for some reason. Thanks for any help!

Comment: `wrapAnimation` would be a starting point, but what's actually trigger the updates?

Comment: The update is triggered in a separate class. Pretty much when update is called in the game loop

Comment: I tried getting rid of wrap animation completly but i get a ton of errors

Comment: What do you mean, getting rid of `wrapAnimation` completely? You should be commenting a single line out, which shouldn't, as far as I can tell, break anything.

Comment: Thats what i thought as well but when i comment out currentFrameIndex = 0; in wrapAnimation() it automatically skips to then last frame so there is no animation unless i set the time for each frame to .5  but that is too slow of an animation

Comment: I have no idea why the length of the animation has any effect on wether it plays or not.

Comment: Oh also one more thing. When i set the time for each frame to .5 it  plays but it starts half way through the animation

Comment: Ok the problem was in where update was called. I had to have an if else statement before the update or else the update was called before animation started and that caused the timer to keep going before anything was rendered. I can post the code if anyone is interested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting rid of the line `currentFrameIndex = 0` in the method `wrapAnimation()` ended up working. It turns out the problem was in another class where `update()` was being called. The animation timer was starting too early in some cases causing it to skip frames.